# What do you call the wearer of a powered exoskeleton?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the wearer of a powered exoskeleton? I am wondering if "pilot" is the word used. I have seen some people refer to Tony Stark as the pilot of the Iron Man suit, but I haven't seen it often enough to prompt me to think this is the correct word to refer to the wearer? Do we just say wearer, or is there a more specific term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far there is no other word used than "Pilot".

Comment: What about operator?

Comment: Exoskeleton Pilot gives 2 580 results in google, while exoskeleton operator only 245